# Solving an ODE with two dependent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here $\theta\equiv\theta(x),y\equiv y(x)$. Need to solve $\theta''y+2\theta'y'+2y'+2y=0$ for $y$, possibly in terms of $\theta$ and $x$.

I tried to apply "method of grouping" by multiplying through with $y$,
\begin{align*}
\theta''y^2+2\theta'y'y+2y'y+2y^2=0\\
d(\theta'y^2+y^2)+2y^2=0
\end{align*}

Cannot figure out how to deal with the $2y^2$ above. Trying to avoid some kind of "implicit" solution if possible.

Comment: What makes you believe this has an explicit solution?

Comment: @NinadMunshi nothing. It would make my work easier. This is part of a bigger problem. Anyway, if implicit solution is the only option, what would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\theta''y+2\theta'y'+2y'+2y=0$$
$$\theta''+2(\theta'+1)\frac{y'}{y}+2=0$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=-\frac{\theta''+2}{2(\theta'+1)}$$
$$\ln|y|=-\int \frac{\theta''+2}{2(\theta'+1)} dx+\text{constant}$$
Given a function $\theta(x)$ the function $y(x)$ is :
$$y(x)=C\:\exp\left(-\int \frac{\theta''+2}{2(\theta'+1)} dx \right)$$
In the general case this cannot be simplified in term of $\theta(x)$ without integral.

Of course, if $\theta(x)$ is known explicitly and if the integral can be explicitly expressed, then $y(x)$ is obtained explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiplying by $y$,

$$\theta''y^2+2\theta'yy'+2yy'+2y^2=0$$
can be simplified to
$$(\theta'y^2+y^2)'+2y^2=0$$
or, with $\phi=(\theta+x)'$ and $z=y^2$,
$$(\phi z)'+2z=0.$$

From this,

$$\theta=-\int\frac2{y^2}\left(\int y^2dx+c\right)dx+c'-x.$$